# Powershell search event ID and send email

Tags: powershell

How can I loop a list of servers to see if there is an event ID in past 10 minutes, then send an email. I could not figure it out "foreach" + "if" + "output"

```
$serverlist = get-content "c:\serverlist.txt"
Foreach ($server in $serverlist) {
  Get-Eventlog -LogName System -EntryType Error -after (get-date).AddMinutes(-20) 
     if ($_.EventID -eq 7036)
          {send email}
}
```

It wont work, where am I doing wrong?

Comment: what part doesnt work? What error are you getting?

Comment: the if part wont work, it lists all error log, event ID is not filtered.

Comment: You can filter your get-eventlog like this:     `Get-EventLog "system" -EntryType Error -after (get-date).AddMinutes(-20) | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq 7036}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reasons why your approach would not be working

- Your log result set and `if` statement are in no way connected. You are returning all records to standard out. Your if is effectively checking if $null is equal to 7036 which would never be true.
- `$_` is an empty pipeline object since you are using the variable `$server` to represent that.
- You are not even looking at remote computers since you did not specify `-ComputerName`.

You can filter all of your criteria into the cmdlet itself. No post processing required which will make it run faster.

```
Get-Eventlog -LogName System -EntryType Error -after (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-20) -ID 7036 -ComputerName $server
```

So if you capture that into a variable you could change your `if`

```
$results = Get-Eventlog ....
if($results){"send mail"}
```

However I would consider collecting all results and sending one mail.

```
$computersWithEvents = Get-Content $path | 
    Where-Object{Get-Eventlog -LogName System -EntryType Error -after (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-10) -ID 7036 -ComputerName $_}
```

This way `$computersWithEvents` contains all of the servers with that have a 7036 event that occurred within the last 10 minutes. You can send that in one mail now.

You can also try using `Get-WinEvent` which should be easy to swap out for what you have. It is arguably faster then `Get-WinEvent`

Comment: Good point of missing pipeline object. The script running supper slow, it takes mins to run on each server.

Comment: @RootLoop Consider using `Get-WinEvent` instead. Apparently it has a performance boon by comparison https://www.mcbsys.com/blog/2011/04/powershell-get-winevent-vs-get-eventlog/. Out of scope for this but if you should look into parallel processing / jobs

Answer (score 2):

A) (Get-Content)Get List of Servers from Serverlist

B) (Foreach) Loop through each server in list

C) Get Events with entry Type "Error" from computer name from serverlist. Where Errors Event ID  is equal to 7036

D) IF Errors are greater then 0 then send list of all errors

```
$serverlist = get-content "c:\serverlist.txt"
foreach ($server in $serverlist){
    $Errors = Get-Eventlog -ComputerName $Server -LogName System -EntryType Error -after (get-date).AddMinutes(-20) | Where-Object {$_.EventID -eq '7036'}
    if($Errors.Length -gt 0){
        Send-MailMessage -To test@test.com -From errors@test.com -Subject "ERRORS"  -Body $ErrorEvents
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference in using Get-WinEvent?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer I wrote this 3 years ago.  But i used it because the person in the question used it. I usually try and stick with the same commands in the questions, But if I was to make my own from scratch it I would use Get-WinEvent. Also i wouldn't use a foreach .. instead foreach-object and pipe it all making a single pipe command.

Comment: Hi @arcset, yes, that doesmake sense.
thank you for the response back mate.